# CustomControl with TemplateParts

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I created a CustomControl that has two TemplateParts.

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfCustomControlLibrary1
{
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_ControlsLayer", Type = typeof (ContentPresenter))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_DisplayLayer", Type = typeof (ContentPresenter))]
    public class CustomControl1 : Control
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlsLayerProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ControlsLayer", typeof (object), typeof (CustomControl1),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayLayerProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayLayer", typeof (object), typeof (CustomControl1),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        private ContentPresenter partControlsLayer;
        private ContentPresenter partDisplayLayer;

        static CustomControl1()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof (CustomControl1),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof (CustomControl1)));
        }


        public object ControlsLayer
        {
            get { return GetValue(ControlsLayerProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ControlsLayerProperty, value); }
        }

        public object DisplayLayer
        {
            get { return GetValue(DisplayLayerProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DisplayLayerProperty, value); }
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            ApplyTemplate();

            partControlsLayer = GetTemplateChild("PART_ControlsLayer") as ContentPresenter;


            partDisplayLayer = GetTemplateChild("PART_DisplayLayer") as ContentPresenter;

            if (partControlsLayer == null || partDisplayLayer == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("Template parts not available");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the Generic.xaml I defined the ControlTemplate and a Default-Setter for the DisplayLayer (one of the TemplateParts). Finaly I set this as the Template of CustomControl1.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaulTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ControlsLayer"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding ControlsLayer}" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_DisplayLayer"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding DisplayLayer}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Style.Resources>

        <Setter Property="DisplayLayer">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding FunctionName, FallbackValue=Functionname}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding DisplayValue, FallbackValue=0.0dB}" Foreground="Lime"
                               Background="Black" />
                </Grid>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DefaulTemplate}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl2}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:CustomControl1}}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now I create a CustomControl2 BasedOn CustomControl1.

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfCustomControlLibrary1
{
    public class CustomControl2 : CustomControl1
    {
        static CustomControl2()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl2), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl2)));
        }
    }
}
```

Then I put both Controls on a WpfWindow.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfCustomControlLibrary1="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfCustomControlLibrary1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <wpfCustomControlLibrary1:CustomControl1 Grid.Row="0"/>

        <wpfCustomControlLibrary1:CustomControl2 Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Problem is I see the Defaulttemplate only on the second Control. I can't find a solution for this, please help.

@gomi42 - if I change Generic.xaml to this:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1">

    <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaulTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ControlsLayer"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding ControlsLayer}" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_DisplayLayer"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding DisplayLayer}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Style.Resources>

        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DefaulTemplate}"/>

        <Setter Property="DisplayLayer">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding FunctionName, FallbackValue=Functionname}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding DisplayValue, FallbackValue=0.0dB}" Foreground="Lime"
                                Background="Black" />
                </Grid>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl2}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

nothing changes! It's still visible only in the second control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

It's the DependencyProperty which causes the problem. I implemented the CustomControl like the examples on this site:
http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/04/how-to-implement-template-binding-in.html

and what should I say this example is wrong!

Here is how it works.

First CustomControl.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using WpfCustomControlLibrary1.Annotations;

namespace WpfCustomControlLibrary1
{
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_ControlsLayer", Type = typeof (Grid))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_DisplayLayer", Type = typeof(ContentControl))]
    public class CustomControl1 : Control
    {
        private Grid partControlsLayer;
        private ContentControl partDisplayLayer;

        static CustomControl1()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof (CustomControl1),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof (CustomControl1)));
        }

        public CustomControl1()
        {
            DataContext = this;
        }


        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            ApplyTemplate();

            partControlsLayer = GetTemplateChild("PART_ControlsLayer") as Grid;


            partDisplayLayer = GetTemplateChild("PART_DisplayLayer") as ContentControl;

            if (partControlsLayer == null || partDisplayLayer == null)
            {
                //throw new NullReferenceException("Template parts not available");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1">

    <Style x:Key="DefaultTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding FunctionName, FallbackValue=Functionname}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding DisplayValue, FallbackValue=0.0dB}" Foreground="Lime"
                                   Background="Black" />
                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="PART_DisplayLayer" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_ControlsLayer" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding FunctionName, FallbackValue=Functionname}" />
                            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding DisplayValue, FallbackValue=0.5dB}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl2}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="PART_DisplayLayer" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_ControlsLayer" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Depp" />
                            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding DisplayValue, FallbackValue=1.0dB}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

CustomControl2.cs as Derived-Class

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfCustomControlLibrary1
{
    public class CustomControl2 : CustomControl1
    {
        static CustomControl2()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl2), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl2)));
        }

        public CustomControl2()
        {
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow still the same.

This is working since nothing of content is static.

Answer (score 0):

The style you created only applies to CustomControl1 because of this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
...
```

You need to create a new style for CustomControl2 e.g. by inheriting:

```
<Style x:Key="MyBase" TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
...
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}" BasedOn={StaticResource MyBase} />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl2}" BasedOn={StaticResource MyBase} />
```

Comment: I don't understand. If I do so, where do I place the setter for Template Property?

Comment: It seem, like somewhat is static and so only visible at the last control which uses this style. Try to add another row in MainWindow and add a third control (another CustomControl2 e.g.). It is again the last control which show the content.